# What all could be the reasons for a NavigationCancel event to get triggered?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a subscription for router events in `angular2`, When I console the events, I find a `NavigationCancel` event with `reason: ""`. Curious to know what all could be the reasons for a `NavigationCancel` to get triggered. Not only with an `empty` reason but in general.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`NavigationCancel` will be triggered when you are trying to naviggate to a route and navigated route children can not be loaded (CanLoad guard) or route itself cannot be activated (CanActivate guard)

you may use `{enableTracing : true}` while configuring `RouterModule` to see all events, and analyze further.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Okay thank you :), away from work, will look into this tomorrow.

Comment: Okay, `enableTracing` is certainly a very nice configuration. Thanks!

Comment: You could give this a vote: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22799

Answer (score 2):

This is late, but i hope it might help someone else, as I had struggled with this also.

So, another reason this could be happening is that the navigation event is triggered twice.

This happened to me by mistake, because i had a component with a `routerLink` directive that had an input binding with the same name:

my-component Class:

```
@Input() routerLink: string[];
```

my-component Template:

```
...
<a [routerLink]="routerLink">
...
```

The parent component template was like this :

```
...
<my-component
   [routerLink]="somePath"
   ...
>
```

Which was actually creating another `routerLink` directive binding.
As a result the navigation event was firing twice, almost simultaneously, which produced the `NavigationCancel` event.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason was an empty children path with an additional guard.

```
{
path: '',
canActivate: [AuthGuard],
component: Dashboard,
children: [
  {
    path: 'x',
    canActivate: [XGuard],
    component: XComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [YGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'z',
        loadChildren: async () => ...,
        canActivate: [ZGuard],
      },
    ]
  }
]
}
```

In the given example `AuthGuard` and `YGuard` must be true to access the Dashboard component.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** For Angular v10, search for calls to `navigateByUrl` and `navigate`.

For Angular 10, you can still get this issue, even though the original question was for `angular2`. I came here searching for an answer for v10.

As mentioned by ktsangop and Madhu Ranjan, this happens when navigation event is triggered twice.

If you switch on `enableTracing` you may see this:

```
NavigationStart {id: 2, url: '/', navigationTrigger: 'imperative', restoredState: null}
```

[The documents for NavigationStart](https://v10.angular.io/api/router/NavigationStart#properties) state that:

> An imperative trigger is a call to router.navigateByUrl() or router.navigate().

So you can search for calls to either of those functions.