# On click, redirect to a route for which canActive returned false once

Tags: angular, router, canactivate, canactivatechild

I have a guard on a route with 3 children. I land in a `ZeroStateComponent` when I do not have data. In the `ZeroStateComponent`, I have a `Get started` button which is supposed to land me to the `Admin` route again. 
Nothing is happening when I click on `Get Started`. `nopermissions` is still accessible but somehow `admin`route is not loading. Is it because `canActivate` has already returned `false` once?

```
  { path: "nopermissions", component: NoPermissionsComponent },
  { path: "nodata", component: ZeroStateComponent }, {
  path: "", canActivate: [FeatureFlagGuardService], canActivateChild: [AdminDataGuardService],
  children: [
    { path: "", redirectTo: "admin", pathMatch: "full" },
    { path: "admin", loadChildren: "../modules/admin.module#AdminModule" },
    { path: "**", redirectTo: "admin" }
  ]
}
]
```

Comment: What Angular version are you using? Is it 9.0?

Comment: On 7 right now. Moving to 8 next month

Comment: You want to go from `nodata` again to `nodata` after the button click?

Comment: I want to go to admin on click on no data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44371818/what-all-could-be-the-reasons-for-a-navigationcancel-event-to-get-triggered
This is what is happening with me. Anything I could do to override this?

Comment: Would it be possible to recreate the issue in a stackblitz?

Comment: Thanks guys, I figured it out. The canActivate is getting triggered again and resulting into landing into noData again. I had to set a flag to mark that I have visited the guard once, and return true on second execution.